# DaggerHilt @Singleton injection returning diferent instances

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronization, singleton, dagger-hilt

So I have ann Android app with dagger hilt that its injecting dependencies, but when I'm using the viewmodel alongside the SyncAdapter it receives an different instance of TableDao which causes my observables in the viewmodel to not update in real-time when the SyncAdapter insert or updates data in the table from retrofit service

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SyncService:Service() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var syncAdapter: SyncAdapter

...

}

class SyncAdapter @Inject constructor(
    private val TableDAO: TableDAO,
) :AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter(context,true,true) {
...
}

@HiltViewModel
class TableViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val TableRepository: TableReposiitory
){
...
}

class TableRepository @Inject constructor(
    val tableDAO: TableDAO
){
...
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Database =
       .....

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTableDAO(database: Database): TableDAO =
        taurusDatabase.TableDao()

}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class TableFragment : Fragment() {

    private val TableViewModel:TableViewModel by viewModels()

}
```

I have tried creating an entrypoint and moving the injection to it, but it didn't work, i also didnt find anything in particular

Comment: 1. Do you observe data with flow or livedata? 
2. Are you sure the problem is in different instances, could you pls log instances to make sure they are different ?

Comment: @TimurPanzhiev Yes, I logged both instances HashCode and got different two different ones, and I do observe it with livedata, when I change using the ViewModel in runtime not via SyncAdapter it does observe correctly, sorry for the late answear

Comment: @TimurPanzhiev I have also checked the ProvideDatabase function running twice, once for the SyncAdapter and other for the runtime viewModels, even though I do inject the same way in all of them

Comment: probably the reason is your SyncAdapter works in a different process?

Comment: My sync adapter does run in a service, but I do create the module SingletonComponent so in theory it should work

Comment: Each process will have its own instance of the singleton, and they are in no way related to each other. So if the process is different from the application process then  your singleton won't work across these entities

Comment: So using a content provider and delegating to it the access to database would it work ?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you definitely have to do one of two things: either work in the same process or implement your own IPC mechanism to pass events from process to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your adapter and app work in different processes and therefore `singletons` in your case do not work. You are running 2 different database instances. But the room has a mechanism for transferring the broadcast from one process to another. Config [enableMultiInstanceInvalidation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()) should help you.